# Spark: reduce/aggregate by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala, so I have no idea how this kind of problem is called (which makes searching for it pretty hard).

I have data of the following structure:

```
[(date1, (name1, 1)), (date1, (name1, 1)), (date1, (name2, 1)), (date2, (name3, 1))]
```

In some way, this has to be reduced/aggregated to:

```
[(date1, [(name1, 2), (name2, 1)]), (date2, [(name3, 1)])]
```

I know how to do `reduceByKey` on a list of key-value pairs, but this particular problem is a mystery to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data, but here goes, step-wise:

```
val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(Array( ("d1",("A",1)), ("d1",("A",1)), ("d1",("B",1)), ("d2",("E",1)) ),2)
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(x => ((x._1, x._2._1), x._2._2))
val rdd3 = rdd2.groupByKey
val rdd4 = rdd3.map{ 
   case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum) 
}
val rdd5 =  rdd4.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._2))).groupByKey
rdd5.collect
```

returns:

```
res28: Array[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])] = Array((d2,CompactBuffer((E,1))), (d1,CompactBuffer((A,2), (B,1))))
```

Better approach avoiding groupByKey is as follows:

```
val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(Array( ("d1",("A",1)), ("d1",("A",1)), ("d1",("B",1)), ("d2",("E",1)) ),2)
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(x => ((x._1, x._2._1), (x._2._2))) // Need to add quotes around V part for reduceByKey
val rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(_+_)
val rdd4 = rdd3.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._2))).groupByKey // Necessary Shuffle
rdd4.collect
```

As I stated in the columns it can be done with DataFrames for structured data, so run this below:

```
// This above should be enough.
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val rddA = sc.makeRDD(Array( ("d1","A",1), ("d1","A",1), ("d1","B",1), ("d2","E",1) ),2)
val dfA = rddA.toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val dfB = dfA
   .groupBy("c1", "c2")
   .agg(sum("c3").alias("sum"))
dfB.show
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+
| c1| c2|sum|
+---+---+---+
| d1|  A|  2|
| d2|  E|  1|
| d1|  B|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

But you can do this to approximate the above of the CompactBuffer above.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

case class XY(x: String, y: Long)
val xyTuple = udf((x: String, y: Long) => XY(x, y))

val dfC = dfB
         .withColumn("xy", xyTuple(col("c2"), col("sum")))
         .drop("c2")
         .drop("sum")

dfC.printSchema
dfC.show

// Then ... this gives you the CompactBuffer answer but from a DF-perspective
val dfD = dfC.groupBy(col("c1")).agg(collect_list(col("xy")))   
dfD.show
```

returns - some renaming req'd and possible sorting:

```
---+----------------+
| c1|collect_list(xy)|
+---+----------------+
| d2|        [[E, 1]]|
| d1|[[A, 2], [B, 1]]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: It strikes me also that this is structured data that could be handled by a data frame / data set with SQL - easier.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Will get back later on this

Comment: If you really want the output that way you asked then what I stated is fine. I was wondering why you would not want DFs. But if that is not the case, then we leave as as else we need to convert Row type to RDD which can get a bit painful.

Comment: Well, if it turns out that DFs would work better, I would switch. I only started learning spark this week, so I don't yet have a clear picture of the cases in which RDDs or DFs would be better. I would be happy to learn why you would favor DFs :)

Comment: Ok. I will add to the answer when I get back from JFK. np. 36 hrs

Comment: Am adding to answer on the DF approach.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. DFs make a lot of sense!

Comment: I stll think that RDDs are handy in the case of some unstructured aspects. But we are moving towards DF and dataSETs. But I leave that latter to you. Success.